# Translate a normal for loop structure into list comprehension structure

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I tried to translate the following structure:

```
newDV = []
for row in dataVector:
   for cell in row:
      newDV.append((cell if row.index(cell) != 0 else 'other'))
```

In the following list comprehension structure:

```
[
    cell
    for cell in row
    for row in dataVector
    if row.index(cell) != 0 else 'other'
]
```

but unfortunately I get the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment

I can't understand where I am wrong. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing the order of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[
    cell
    for row in dataVector
    for cell in row
    if row.index(cell) != 0 else 'other'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be working for you, this uses python ternary operator (<if_false>, <if_true>)[test]

```
[
    ('other', cell)[row.index(cell)!=0]
    for row in dataVector
    for cell in row
]
```

Comment: I had never seen this use of the ternary operator... Thanks, I'll take a cue!

Comment: python doesnot have a ternary operator, this a way of achieving it

Comment: Yes it has it. It has been added since version 2.5: `a if condition else b`